# In which cases would AdaBoost outperform Random Forest?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, adaboost

I have heard people claim (for example in the course [Intro to machine learning](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud120) , lesson 5) that they like the adaboost algorithm without really providing the reason for why.

At the same time, i have briefly gone through the paper [Explaining the Success of AdaBoost and Random Forests as
Interpolating Classifiers](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume18/15-240/15-240.pdf)
, which suggest that the two are in essence relatively similar.

But in reading about these algorithms i could not find arguments on why to choose one over the other. So my questions are:

1. When and why should AdaBoost outperform the random forest?
2. What are the other advantages of adaboost over random forest?
3. When and why should random forest outperform the adaboost?
4. what are the other advantages of random forest over the adaboost?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112148/when-to-avoid-random-forest/112151#112151